# Why django form input is not being saved in database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created a form which will take input and save input values in database(mysql). My forms.py

```
class postcreation(forms.Form):
    post_title = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name':'post_title'}))
    post_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name':'post_name'}))
    post_post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'name':'post_post'}))
```

My models.py

```
class postdata(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.ForeignKey(userdata, on_delete='CASECADE')
    post = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

At first I had not used the 'attr' value. It didn't work. I saw a stackoverflow answer which says that I should. Still no luck.

My views.py

```
def postinput(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = postcreation(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            inputpost = postdata(title=request.POST['post_title'], name=request.POST['post_name'], post=request.POST['post_post'])
            inputpost.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = postcreation()

    context = { 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'firstapp/postinput.html', context)
```

html template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'index' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

I was trying to get input through form and save it to database. But I was not being able to do so. I cannot understand why. I was going through some of the tutorials and some stackoverflow questions. It still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to add `print(from.errors)` before `context = ` or add to the template `{{form.errors}}`

Comment: always inspect `request.POST` in your debugger (or by printing it) to understand what's going it. And yes, @NS0 is correct with the answer below that you should not save the POST data directly but use the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary to access the values. Using the POST data opens up hacking vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your view does not save if `form.is_valid()` returns false.  As @BearBrown commented, the html template ought to display the form errors, so you know when something went wrong.

Comment: so you see any errors in your HTML form? or in your console?

Comment: From this example, it looks like you're building a form to create instances of a model. There's nothing wrong with that, especially as a learning exercise, but the usual way to do it in a real Django project would be to use the built in `modelform` classes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Yes. After adding {{form.errors}} in the template it says my `name=form.cleaned_data.get('post_name')` is not valid. But the value I entered does exist in userdata table.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I got it. As a beginner I just wanted to do as simple as possible. thanks.

Comment: did you input `Primary Key` of the parent model?

Comment: Thanks to every one. After getting the cleaned_data and linking with matching foreign key value it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values from the validated form instead of the request directly, like this:

```
    # . . .
    if form.is_valid()
        inputpost = postdata(title=form.cleaned_data.get('title'), 
                             name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'), 
                             post=form.cleaned_data.get('post'))
    # . . .
```

---

Since `postdata.name` is a userdata object, you need to point it to one. For example, doing something like this

```
    if form.is_valid()
        inputpost = postdata(title=form.cleaned_data.get('title'),
                             post=form.cleaned_data.get('post'))

        name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        inputpost.name = userdata.objects.get(name=name) # or something similar, 
                                                         # depending on what exactly 
                                                         #`userdata` is and how 
                                                         # to get the relevant instance.
        inputpost.save()
```

I am not sure exactly how to fetch the `userdata` post, since that depends on the rest of your code, but it's something like that.

It might also be the case that you want to create a new `userdata` object instead. That would be something like:

```
        # . . . 
        name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        ud = userdata(name=name)
        ud.save()
        inputpost.name = ud, 
        inputpost.save()
        # . . .
```

Again, depends on what `userdata` is.

Comment: why you think the form is valid?

Comment: I assume that he only wants to save the object if the form is valid

Comment: and me too, but why you think the trouble only in the way to get data?

Comment: I tried this but it shows an error. `Cannot assign "'alom'": "postdata.name" must be a "userdata" instance.` But "alom" is a userdata value.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @NS0 read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012205/why-django-form-input-is-not-being-saved-in-database#comment98669846_56012205

Comment: Thanks @NS0 .  I edited the name input to connect userdata model and it worked. 
       `name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        inputpost.name = userdata.objects.get(name=name)`  It worked that way. thanks.